# Banach spaces partial derivatives [Proof verification]

Tags: proof-verification, banach-spaces

I want to prove the following proposition but I'm not sure my proof is correct. I would apreciate if someone can check if it's correct, thanks.

Let $U \subset E=E_1 \times E_2 \dots\times E_n$, where $E_i$ is a Banach space por every $i$ and $V \subset F$, $F$ a Banach space ($U,V$ open). If $f:U \rightarrow V$ is $C^1$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} $ is continuous.

$\textit{Proof:}$
I've already seen that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} =Df(x) \circ \iota$ where $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ and $\iota$ is the canonical inclusion. 
So I want to see that Df(x) \circ \iota is continuous on $x$, then let $x_0 \in U$ and let's see that $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|| x-x_0|| <\delta \Rightarrow ||Df(x)\circ\iota - Df(x_0)\circ\iota || < \epsilon$

$||Df(x)\circ\iota - Df(x_0)\circ\iota || \\
= Sup ||Df(x)\circ\iota(v) - Df(x_0)\circ\iota(v) ||  \\
= Sup ||(Df(x)-Df(x_0))(\iota(v)) || \\
\leq Sup ||Df||\cdot||x-x_0||\cdot||\iota(v)|| \\
\leq ||Df||\cdot ||\iota||\cdot||x-x_0|| < \epsilon \\
$

The first equality is by definition of the norm on $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$, the third one is because $Df \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ and the last one because the only dependance on $v$ is on $\iota$ then $Sup (\iota(v)) = || \iota||$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a little too late, but you can define another map $C_{\iota}: \mathcal{L}(E,F)\to \mathcal{L}(E_i, F)$ by
\begin{equation}
C_{\iota}(T) = T \circ \iota,
\end{equation}
the "composition  by $\iota$ map".  $C$ is a bounded (equivalently continuous) linear map, with $\rVert C \lVert \leq \rVert \iota \lVert$, because
\begin{align}
\lVert C_{\iota}(T) \rVert = \lVert T \circ \iota \rVert \leq \lVert T \rVert \cdot \lVert \iota \rVert,
\end{align}
the last inequality being true because we use the operator norm (the one with $\sup$) throughout. With this, we have that for any $\xi \in U$,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\xi) &= Df(\xi) \circ \iota \\
&= C_{\iota}\left( Df(\xi)\right) \\
&= \left( C_{\iota} \circ Df \right)(\xi)
\end{align}
Since by assumption $Df: U \to \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ is continuous, and by the reasoning above, $C_{\iota}$ is also continuous, their composition is also continuous, thereby proving that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\cdot) : U \to \mathcal{L}(E_i, F)$ is continuous.